# best way to construct datalist with mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

What is the best way to construct a html5 [datalist](http://davidwalsh.name/datalist) with mojolicious?

I looked for a tag helper but did not find a tag helper for constructing it.

Here is an example of a datalist:

```
<datalist id="frameworks">
    <option value="MooTools">
    <option value="Moobile">
    <option value="Dojo Toolkit">
    <option value="jQuery">
    <option value="YUI">
</datalist>
```

The list is dynamic and is fetched from a db, so i cannot use a static html chunk.

There are similar tag helpers, e.g. for a `<select>` tag I can put into my template:

```
%= select_field country => [[Germany => 'de'], 'en']
```

which produces:

```
<select name="country">
  <option value="de">Germany</option>
  <option value="en">en</option>
</select>
```

but I couldn't find anything regarding a datalist in the [default tag helpers](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/TagHelpers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while, but maybe will find it useful.

In the controller, you need to have an array with some items. Let's create it:

```
my @levelsArray = ();
for (my $i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    push @levelsArray, "level00".$i;
}
```

After that, send it to the template:

```
get '/index' => sub {
    my ( $mojo ) = @_;
    $mojo -> stash ('levelsArray' => \@levelsArray);
    $mojo -> render (template => 'index' );
};
```

and finally, render it using:

```
<%= select_field 'levelSelected' => [ @{ stash('levelsArray') }] %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how this is mojolicious specific, but wouldn't simple html in your template would be enough:

```
<datalist id="frameworks">
    <option value="MooTools">
    <option value="Moobile">
    <option value="Dojo Toolkit">
    <option value="jQuery">
    <option value="YUI">
</datalist>
<input type="text" list="frameworks" />
```

**EDIT**

Let me clarify, this wouldn't be static HTML in your template...you would fetch your data within controller and pass that data to template which would construct this kind of HTML with it's templating engine.

Comment: Hi, The list is dynamic and is fetched from the database. So i can't use static html. I can construct the list alone with a simple loop but wanted to know if there is some tag helper available.

Comment: Well in your controller you would get options for datalist, forward that to template and render it there like this? So template won't be static...

Comment: @SlavenTomac I think you misunderstood what OP was trying to actually do. I updated the question to show a similar tag helper in action. Just stating that a template could manually construct such a list wherever needed is not helpful – this is the obvious solution which OP is trying to avoid. Tag helpers are a more expressive solution.